# Linux PDF to TIFF Quality Issue

Tags: pdf, tiff, ghostscript

I am trying to use a linux application to convert .pdf files to .tiff for faxing, however, our clients have not been happy with the quality of GhostScript's tiffg4 device.

In the image below, the left side shows a conversion using GhostScript tiffg4 and the right is from an online conversion service. We are unable to see which application is being used to attain that quality.

*Note*: The output TIFF must be black & white

Ghostscript Code:

```
gs -sDEVICE=tiffg4 -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dPDFFitPage -sPAPERSIZE=letter -g1728x2156 -sOutputFile=testg4.tiff test.pdf
```

We have tried these GhostScript devices:

- tiffcrle
- tiffg3
- tiffg32d
- tiffg4
- tifflzw
- tiffpack

My question is this--does anyone know which application and/or setting is used to achieve the quality on the right?

[image: TIFF Quality]

Comment: The 'device' is not the issue. The ones you listed are for compressing the image data, not for doing the color reduction. The image on the left uses a fixed pattern "ordered dither" while the one on the right uses what's called a "error diffusion" dither.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extending on BitBank's comment, you could write a RGB tiff and then use ImageMagick to convert to Group 4. ImageMagick allows you to control the dithering algorithm:

```
gs -sDEVICE=tiff24nc -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dPDFFitPage -sPAPERSIZE=letter  -g1728x2156 -sOutputFile=intermediate.tiff your.pdf
convert intermediate.tiff -dither FloydSteinberg -compress group4 out.tiff
```

[ImageMagick's manual](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/quantize/#dither_error) has some background on the algorithm(s) and available options.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was everything I needed!

Comment: Yes, we have tried but not able to achieve good quality same as the original.
We have posted similar issue, So please check and help here if possible.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52038634/convert-pdf-to-tiff-with-same-quality/52039987#52039987